# BroadcastReceiver not triggered when screen off - possible reasons?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager, android-pendingintent

Try to find out what keeps my BroadcastReceiver from being triggered when screen is off.
The trigger "arrives" delayed, the moment the screen gets unlocked. When screen is on, the receiver gets triggered in time.

*Issues occur on android 4.4.2 (Danew Dslide 710), code works well on many other devices*

**The PendingIntent is passed to the AlarmManager like so:**

```
Context context = getApplicationContext();
Intent intent = new Intent("com.myapp.TEST_ACTION");
intent.putExtra(XTRA_KEY_CONFIG_ID, id);

if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_RECEIVER_FOREGROUND);

PendingIntent alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, reqCode, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
AlarmManger am = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
am.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, alarmTime, alarmIntent);
```

*I run the above code inside a service, but use the application context for AlarmManager.*

**The manifest looks as follows:**

```
...
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DISABLE_KEYGUARD"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
...

<receiver android:name=".AlarmTriggerReceiver"
      android:exported="false">
      <intent-filter>
          <action android:name="com.myapp.TEST_ACTION" />
      </intent-filter>
 </receiver>
```

**My receiver code:**

```
public class AlarmTriggerReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
 {
       @Override
        public void onReceive(final Context argCTX, Intent intent)
        {
            // writing a log entry here, but see it delayed at the time 
            // the screen gets unlocked only
            // onReceive gets called in time when device screen is on
        }
    }
```

As code in Application-class is called prior the trigger gets called, i removed all code in Application class (init google analytics) to make sure it doesn't hang arround there for some reason.

The code behaves as if i would have used Alarmmanagers ".set" (instead of ".setExact"), so i think the issue might be related to power-management.

Other alarm apps, like google's descclock work well on that device.

**Any suggestions and ideas are highly appreciated!**

**Edit 1:**

The BroadcastReceiver is triggered in time when after setting the PendingIntent to AlarmManager the apps activity is still visible and screen locks itself (some seconds later). When pressing ***HOME*** and after locking the screen manually using the ***POWER*** button the above problem occurs.

Comment: Some users reported the same problem for my app on a Nexus 6 with 7.0, so the problem appears to be more generic. I'm looking for a solution as well.

Comment: do you have found a solution?